# Finding skipped index time steps and filling the values in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am working with a pandas `DataFrame` that has an index that skips one or more time steps which in my case is one or more hours. I want to know if there is a way to find these time step skips and possibly insert these missing time steps.

Example of what I have:

```py
[In]: df
[Out]:
                    point_value
Timestamp   
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2550.63
2016-01-01 01:00:00 2535.97
2016-01-01 02:00:00 2538.25
2016-01-01 04:00:00 2548.63
2016-01-01 05:00:00 2555.16
```

Example of what I am looking for:

```py
[In]: df
[Out]:
                    point_value
Timestamp   
2016-01-01 02:00:00 2538.25
2016-01-01 04:00:00 2548.63
```

Ideally after finding these time step gaps I'd want to fill them with the time steps missing as such:

```py
[In]: df
[Out]:
                    point_value
Timestamp   
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2550.63
2016-01-01 01:00:00 2535.97
2016-01-01 02:00:00 2538.25
2016-01-01 03:00:00 NaN
2016-01-01 04:00:00 2548.63
2016-01-01 05:00:00 2555.16
```

I have searched on stack overflow and can't seem to find something that pertains to the index itself. If this is a duplicated question then I will be happy to take it down and find the result.  Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`DataFrame.reindex` should achieve what you are looking for. Just define a new index and apply it to your dataframe:

```
new_index = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2016 0:0:0', end='1/1/2016 5:0:0', periods=6)
df.reindex(index=new_index)
```

Answer (score 1):

With exactly hourly timestamps you can use `resample`

```
df.resample('H').first()

                     point_value
Timestamp                       
2016-01-01 00:00:00      2550.63
2016-01-01 01:00:00      2535.97
2016-01-01 02:00:00      2538.25
2016-01-01 03:00:00          NaN
2016-01-01 04:00:00      2548.63
2016-01-01 05:00:00      2555.16
```